# Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Spigot Minecraft

Tags: java, minecraft, spigot

i'm trying to install spigot server on debian 10, when i run start.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true
do
java -Xms4G -Xmx4G -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 - 
XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -$
echo "restarting in 10"
sleep 10
done
```

i've got this output:
[image]

i don't have any idea on how to fix it, any help?

Comment: is this in a separate line "XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions" ? Also what is this "-$" ?

Comment: no it is on the same line, i didn't write this script, i got it here:
https://www.vultr.com/docs/setup-spigot-on-debian-10/

Comment: There was some issue with your copy paste, that line is much longer in the link you just sent.

Answer (score 2):

The script seems to require an argument which should be the jar name.

Also, you put a wrong back to break line ("\n") which seems to break the bash.

For me, you should replace `-$` by the jar file or spigot, like that:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
while true
do
java -Xms4G -Xmx4G -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions spigot-1.18.jar
echo "Restarting in 10 seconds"
sleep 10
done
```

Answer (score 2):

The script is not correct.

```
#!/bin/sh
while true
do
java -Xms4G -Xmx4G -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:G1NewSizePercent=30 -    XX:G1MaxNewSizePercent=40 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=8M -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:G1HeapWastePercent=5 -XX:G1MixedGCCountTarget=4 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=15 -XX:G1MixedGCLiveThresholdPercent=90 -XX:G1RSetUpdatingPauseTimePercent=5 -XX:SurvivorRatio=32 -XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1 -Dusing.aikars.flags=https://mcflags.emc.gs -Daikars.new.flags=true -jar spigot.jar nogui
echo "restarting in 10"
sleep 10
done
```

Reference: https://www.vultr.com/docs/setup-spigot-on-debian-10/